# Rotated Absolutely-Positioned element with Negative Text-Indent Makes Page Very Long

Tags: css

I have  a header with a background image. I styled the header as follows:

```
h1
{
    position:absolute;
    background:url(../somepicture.jpg) no-repeat 0 0 scroll #000;
    height:100px;
    text-indent:-9999em;
    -moz-transform:rotate(-10deg);
    -webkit-transform:rotate(-10deg);
    transform:rotate(-10deg);
    width:200px
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/bw63m/

The page becomes very long. I know this is because of the text-indent with the transform because I tried removing one of those properties and the page became shorter.

How come when the element isn't rotated the width doesn't expand? Is this a CSS bug? This happens in Chrome, Firefox, Internet Explorer. Haven't checked Safari or Opera.

Thanks.

Comment: use `overflow: hidden`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `overflow:hidden` give parent `position:relative` it will not affect the whole page

Comment: Why does this happen only on rotate though?

Comment: you are indenting the text and the indented part has been rotated.slight vertically.so may the indent worked this way.. not sure! else try separate div for box and h1